# Botones inteligentes de paypal, quitar campos del formulario y agregar variables avanzadas

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal, sdk

Estoy implementando una tienda de productos digitales cuyo método de pago es paypal, deseo solo dejar los campos básicos u obligatorios que son número de tarjeta, expiración, código de seguridad, nombre correo y número telefónico, sin embargo en formulario del botón inteligente generado en la página de paypal salen muchos campos que no vienen al caso como la dirección por ejemplo. Como podría quitar estos campos? Adjuntaré dos capturas de como esta, y como quisiera que este, se que esto es del lado del servidor de paypal pero la información es muy confusa y vaga en su página de desarrolladores.

Por otro lado me gustaria agregar variables avanzadas(las dejaré a continuación) al mismo botón para que interactúen con otro complemento de mi sitio web. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, tengo semanas estancado en este problema.

```
notify_url=https://mi_sitio_web/?swpm_process_ipn=1 
custom=subsc_ref=2
```

[image: Así se ve actualmente]
[image: Esto es lo que quiero lograr]

**Adjunto el codigo del boton que utilizando**

```
<div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=My_ID&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
  <script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',
          
        },

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":1}}]
          });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            
            // Full available details
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

            // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
            const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            element.innerHTML = '';
            element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';

            // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            
          });
        },

        onError: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
  </script>
```

Comment: No se ve reflejado semanas de haberlo intentado, como menciona en la descripción de la pregunta. No hay código  mínimo verificable de referencia para atender la pregunta.

Comment: Perdón, he agregado el código

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto la parte de la dirección de envió agregando el siguiente código debajo de  **return actions.order.create({**

Este esta fue la solución:

```
application_context: {
shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
```

Pero aun no soy con una solución para el código postal y las variables avanzadas